# Next.js catch all routes from index with only one getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new to React and Next.js, but after following the doc of dynamic routes I've successfully created a subpage catching all routes, and beeing able to get that on the server side. see the image:

[image: subpage catching all routes]

My problem is that I'd like to have this behaviour from my index.tsx page, to be able to catch everthing on the home page and get the full url. What I've done is rename my index.tsx to [...].tsx and it redirects well to the home page no matter the route. The issue by doing that is my function getServerSideProps is called twice and I've no ideas why.

How should I do to be able to catch every routes from my homepage and get the complete url ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that there is nothing wrong with the code, my issue was a chrome extension.
I've now a page page/[...alias].tsx catching all routes with no problems :).

Comment: What extension please?

Comment: I don't remember the exact name, but it was something like "SAML tracer".

Comment: In my case it something idk, I tried in firefox and it worked, probably some extension that I can't figure out